# Move non-consecutive messages to another room on Mac

Tags: bug, chat

On a Mac you can't seem to move non-consecutive messages to another room because the required command is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click is not passed through to the browser because it emulates a right-click on a Mac.  A <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click simply selects the new message (it does not retain previous selections).

Can this be remedied?

Any workarounds in the meantime?